# Sqlite database utilites class

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite

I am using SQlite as a database in a  C# winforms application.

My project involves some select simple queries, inserts, deletes.

Currently, I have written all these sql, Ado.net queries in the codebehind.

For eg:

```
   private void frmPlant_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FillData();
    }
    void FillData()
    {
        dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
        string query = @"SELECT * FROM  [Table1]";

        using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(connString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            da = new SQLiteDataAdapter(query, conn);
            ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds, "T1");
            dt = ds.Tables[0];
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
            dataGridView1.DataMember = "T1";
            dataGridView1.Columns["TId"].HeaderText = "SNo";
            dataGridView1.Columns["Tcode"].Visible = false;
            dataGridView1.Columns["TID"].Width = 50;
            dataGridView1.Columns["Tcode"].Width = 70;
        }
    }
```

I have quiet a bit of code like this which interacts with the DB.

Question: Instead of writing these ado.net connections, sql query in the code behind, I want to use a 2 tier/3tier architecture. This should involve writing all the database stuff(ado.net execute scalar, reader, sql queries in another DBUtilitesclass/project and simply calling this DBUtilitesclass from the code behind.

Please suggest any tutorials to do this.

PS: I am using sqlite which does not support stored procedures.

Thank u
Sun

Comment: If you are going to 2/3 tier design, then why not also consider ORM like Fluent NHibernate, https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Getting-started?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer

http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-writing-a-dotnet-wrapper-for-sqlite

http://snipplr.com/view/41708/

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22165/Using-SQLite-in-your-C-Application

Hope this helps

Thanks

Deepu